# Load iMenu at initialization

Tags: emacs, elisp, gnu, init

I'm sorry of r a very basic question. I am trying to load iMenu in GNU Emacs at the initialization. Usually it loads by executing `M-x imenu-add-menubar-index`. I understand I need to put something into my `~/.emacs` file, but everything I tried does not work.

I'm new to GNU Emacs and Lisp, what do I need to put there for the index menu to be generated automatically?

Comment: More details on `iMenu` can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943705/gnu-emacs-equivalent-of-func-menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have an Imenu "Index" menu bar item available for all buffers that belong to a certain major mode by adding `imenu-add-menubar-index` to its mode hook. For example,

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'imenu-add-menubar-index)      ; c
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'imenu-add-menubar-index) ; python
```

Comment: perhaps you could help me with something i noticed when putting in this change. This worked for python like you mentioned, but my c customization is called via `c-mode-common-hook`, not as `c-mode-hook`, that you mentioned. Why is that?

Comment: `c-mode-common-hook` is a common hook across many languages (including c, c++, java, and so on), but `c-mode-hook` is specific to the C language. Refer to [CC Hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/CC-Hooks.html) in the CC mode manual.